# Save last record according to a composite key. ksqlDB 0.6.0

Tags: ksqldb, confluent-platform

I have a Kafka topic with the following data flow ( ksqldb_topic_01 ):

```
% Reached end of topic ksqldb_topic_01 [0] at offset 213
{"city":"Sevilla","temperature":20,"sensorId":"sensor03"}
% Reached end of topic ksqldb_topic_01 [0] at offset 214
{"city":"Madrid","temperature":5,"sensorId":"sensor03"}
% Reached end of topic ksqldb_topic_01 [0] at offset 215
{"city":"Sevilla","temperature":10,"sensorId":"sensor01"}
% Reached end of topic ksqldb_topic_01 [0] at offset 216
{"city":"Valencia","temperature":15,"sensorId":"sensor03"}
% Reached end of topic ksqldb_topic_01 [0] at offset 217
{"city":"Sevilla","temperature":15,"sensorId":"sensor01"}
% Reached end of topic ksqldb_topic_01 [0] at offset 218
{"city":"Madrid","temperature":20,"sensorId":"sensor03"}
% Reached end of topic ksqldb_topic_01 [0] at offset 219
{"city":"Valencia","temperature":15,"sensorId":"sensor02"}
% Reached end of topic ksqldb_topic_01 [0] at offset 220
{"city":"Sevilla","temperature":5,"sensorId":"sensor02"}
% Reached end of topic ksqldb_topic_01 [0] at offset 221
{"city":"Sevilla","temperature":5,"sensorId":"sensor01"}
% Reached end of topic ksqldb_topic_01 [0] at offset 222
```

And I want to save in a table the last value that enters me in the topic, for each city and sensorId

In my ksqldDB I create the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE ultimo_resgistro(city VARCHAR,sensorId VARCHAR,temperature INTEGER) WITH (KAFKA_TOPIC='ksqldb_topic_01', VALUE_FORMAT='json',KEY = 'sensorId,city');
```

```
DESCRIBE EXTENDED ULTIMO_RESGISTRO;

Name                 : ULTIMO_RESGISTRO
Type                 : TABLE
Key field            : SENSORID
Key format           : STRING
Timestamp field      : Not set - using <ROWTIME>
Value format         : JSON
Kafka topic          : ksqldb_topic_01 (partitions: 1, replication: 1)

 Field       | Type                      
-----------------------------------------
 ROWTIME     | BIGINT           (system) 
 ROWKEY      | VARCHAR(STRING)  (system) 
 CITY        | VARCHAR(STRING)           
 SENSORID    | VARCHAR(STRING)           
 TEMPERATURE | INTEGER                   
-----------------------------------------
```

Seeing that data is processing me

```
select * from ultimo_resgistro emit changes;
```

```
+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+
|ROWTIME           |ROWKEY            |CITY              |SENSORID          |TEMPERATURE       |
+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+
key cannot be null
Query terminated
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you need to set the key of the Kafka message correctly. You also cannot specify two fields in the `KEY` clause. Read more about this [here](https://docs.ksqldb.io/en/latest/developer-guide/syntax-reference/#key-requirements)

Here's an example of how to do it.

First up, load test data:

```js
kafkacat -b kafka-1:39092 -P -t ksqldb_topic_01 <<EOF
{"city":"Madrid","temperature":20,"sensorId":"sensor03"}
{"city":"Madrid","temperature":5,"sensorId":"sensor03"}
{"city":"Sevilla","temperature":10,"sensorId":"sensor01"}
{"city":"Sevilla","temperature":15,"sensorId":"sensor01"}
{"city":"Sevilla","temperature":20,"sensorId":"sensor03"}
{"city":"Sevilla","temperature":5,"sensorId":"sensor01"}
{"city":"Sevilla","temperature":5,"sensorId":"sensor02"}
{"city":"Valencia","temperature":15,"sensorId":"sensor02"}
{"city":"Valencia","temperature":15,"sensorId":"sensor03"}
EOF
```

Now in ksqlDB declare the schema over the topic - as a stream, because we need to repartition the data to add a key. If you control the producer to the topic then maybe you'd do this upstream and save a step.

```sql
CREATE STREAM sensor_data_raw (city VARCHAR, temperature DOUBLE, sensorId VARCHAR) 
    WITH (KAFKA_TOPIC='ksqldb_topic_01', VALUE_FORMAT='JSON');
```

Repartition the data based on the composite key.

```sql
SET 'auto.offset.reset' = 'earliest';

CREATE STREAM sensor_data_repartitioned WITH (VALUE_FORMAT='AVRO') AS
    SELECT *
      FROM sensor_data_raw
    PARTITION BY city+sensorId;
```

Two things to note:

1. I'm taking the opportunity to reserialise into Avro - if you'd rather keep JSON throughout then just omit the `WITH (VALUE_FORMAT` clause.
2. When the data is repartitioned the ordering guarantees are lost, so in theory you may end up with events out of order after this.

At this point we can inspect the transformed topic:

```sql
ksql> PRINT SENSOR_DATA_REPARTITIONED FROM BEGINNING LIMIT 5;
Format:AVRO
1/24/20 9:55:54 AM UTC, Madridsensor03, {"CITY": "Madrid", "TEMPERATURE": 20.0, "SENSORID": "sensor03"}
1/24/20 9:55:54 AM UTC, Madridsensor03, {"CITY": "Madrid", "TEMPERATURE": 5.0, "SENSORID": "sensor03"}
1/24/20 9:55:54 AM UTC, Sevillasensor01, {"CITY": "Sevilla", "TEMPERATURE": 10.0, "SENSORID": "sensor01"}
1/24/20 9:55:54 AM UTC, Sevillasensor01, {"CITY": "Sevilla", "TEMPERATURE": 15.0, "SENSORID": "sensor01"}
1/24/20 9:55:54 AM UTC, Sevillasensor03, {"CITY": "Sevilla", "TEMPERATURE": 20.0, "SENSORID": "sensor03"}
```

Note that the key in the Kafka message (the second field, after the timestamp) is now set correctly, compared to the original data that had no key:

```sql
ksql> PRINT ksqldb_topic_01 FROM BEGINNING LIMIT 5;
Format:JSON
{"ROWTIME":1579859380123,"ROWKEY":"null","city":"Madrid","temperature":20,"sensorId":"sensor03"}
{"ROWTIME":1579859380123,"ROWKEY":"null","city":"Madrid","temperature":5,"sensorId":"sensor03"}
{"ROWTIME":1579859380123,"ROWKEY":"null","city":"Sevilla","temperature":10,"sensorId":"sensor01"}
{"ROWTIME":1579859380123,"ROWKEY":"null","city":"Sevilla","temperature":15,"sensorId":"sensor01"}
{"ROWTIME":1579859380123,"ROWKEY":"null","city":"Sevilla","temperature":20,"sensorId":"sensor03"}
```

Now we can declare a table over the repartitioned data. Since I'm using Avro now I don't have to reenter the schema. If I was using JSON I would need to enter it again as part of this DDL.

```sql
CREATE TABLE ultimo_resgistro WITH (KAFKA_TOPIC='SENSOR_DATA_REPARTITIONED', VALUE_FORMAT='AVRO');
```

The table's key is implicitly taken from the `ROWKEY`, which is the key of the Kafka message.

```
ksql> SELECT ROWKEY, CITY, SENSORID, TEMPERATURE FROM ULTIMO_RESGISTRO EMIT CHANGES;
+------------------+----------+----------+-------------+
|ROWKEY            |CITY      |SENSORID  |TEMPERATURE  |
+------------------+----------+----------+-------------+
|Madridsensor03    |Madrid    |sensor03  |5.0          |
|Sevillasensor03   |Sevilla   |sensor03  |20.0         |
|Sevillasensor01   |Sevilla   |sensor01  |5.0          |
|Sevillasensor02   |Sevilla   |sensor02  |5.0          |
|Valenciasensor02  |Valencia  |sensor02  |15.0         |
|Valenciasensor03  |Valencia  |sensor03  |15.0         |
```

If you want to take advantage of pull queries (in order to get the latest value) then you need to go and upvote (or contribute a PR ) [this issue](https://github.com/confluentinc/ksql/issues/3985).